# Determine contract (type) from EndpointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an MVC5 application that is communicating successfully with multiple WCF services, I am now adding some custom error handling, and I want to handle EndPointNotFoundExceptions that may arise for whatever reason (most commonly the service simply isn't running so it's endpoint doesn't exist). I would like to be able to feed back to the user which service the application is having trouble connecting to.

By inspecting the exception I can determine the specified Address of the endpoint, but can't seem to find any Binding or Contract information.. is there a way to determine the contract interface/type from an EndPointNotFoundException, or do I need to engineer some manner of looking up which service I attempted to call most recently or something else along those lines?

Comment: In your code where this exception is being thrown you presumably know what end point you are trying to connect to so you can collect this information in the catch block if it isn't already in the Exception. You can then either deal with the exception there or bundle the relevant information up into a new exception of your own and throw it and catch it higher up.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid throw -> catch -> throw -> catch, but if the information isn't in the original exception I guess I'll have to.

Comment: Yeah. And I don't think that there is necessarily any reason to avoid that. I might be wrong but I can't see any problems in it at all. Just make sure your new Exception has a good name and looks right and people reading the code will be happy. I should note though that I don't know that exception so I don't know if there is definitely no way to get the information from the exception which is why I commented rather than answered.